# giving link to datepicker icon gif

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker icon trigger. I want to give the icon link, that is when  the mouse is over the calendar, I want  to change the cursor. How can I do that?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

```
my code is as follows:

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange:"-90:+0",
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif", //my gif is here
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the following CSS (using the class asigned to the image by jQuery UI):

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    cursor: pointer;       
}​
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/8MWaB/).